# How to select elements that have a specific css variable defined in its style tag?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way to select elements that have a specific css variable defined in its style tag? i guess its not available because it would act strange with global variables but maybe there is a way.
for example change this:

```
<div data-icon style="--icon: url(...)"></div>
<style>
div[data-icon]::before {
    ...
    background-image: var(--icon);
    ...
}
</style>
```

to something like that:

```
<div style="--icon: url(...)"></div>
<style>
div:hasvar(--icon)::before {
    ...
    background-image: var(--icon);
    ...
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use attribute selector like your first code:

```css
div[style*="--icon"]::before {
  content: "I have a variable";
  background-image: var(--icon);
}
```

```html
<div style="--icon: url(...)"></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: oh right. i can just use the contains selector for that. its not perfect but good enough. thanks

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to select elements that have a specific css variable
>   defined in its style tag?

Yes. You can use [var()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var) function to do that.

**Note:** You may need to define the variable inside `:root` to make it global

```css
:root {
  --icon: url('https://www.trafalgar.com/real-word/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2019/10/giant-panda-750x400.jpg');
}

div {
    background-image: var(--icon);
    background-size: 100px 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: thats using the variable not selecting the element based on having a variable.